# How to split a 1D numpy array in several horizontal arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm just a Python beginner and I wanted to create a graphic visualisation of Tesla stock prices from a csv file.

I imported the file, created a list then a numpy array (1D)

But I'm not able to slice it in several arrays made of the columns only.
I tried `np.split` and `np.hsplit` but cannot find a way to make it work.

Here is the code

```py
with open('Tesla.csv') as f:
    mylist = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]

import numpy as np
np_mylist = np.array(mylist)
```

Here is a slice of the data :

```
['Date,Close/Last,Volume,Open,High,Low'
 '10/28/2021,$1077.04,27213170,$1068.305,$1081,$1054.2'
 '10/27/2021,$1037.86,38526460,$1039.66,$1070.88,$1030.78'
 '10/26/2021,$1018.43,62414970,$1024.69,$1094.94,$1001.44'
 '10/25/2021,$1024.86,62852100,$950.53,$1045.02,$944.2'
 '10/22/2021,$909.68,22880840,$895.5,$910,$890.96']
```

How can i get one array for date, one for close/last, etc.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Sorry to disturb with such stupid question but i'm not able to find a way myself

Comment: I don't know what you want to do but better use `panda.DataFrame` - it has many useful function. And first run `df = pandas.read_csv('Tesla.csv')` and you get table without running rest of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use `pandas.DataFrame` and you will have resolved all problems.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Tesla.csv')
```

And now you can access every column using `df[column_name]`

```
print( df["Date"] )
```

---

It has also functions to remove `$` and convert `string` to `float`

```
df['Open'] = df['Open'].str.replace('$', '').astype(float)
```

And now it can be ploted

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.plot(x='Date', y='Open')
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Full working code.

I use `io` only to simulate file in memory.

```
text = '''Date,Close/Last,Volume,Open,High,Low
10/28/2021,$1077.04,27213170,$1068.305,$1081,$1054.2
10/27/2021,$1037.86,38526460,$1039.66,$1070.88,$1030.78
10/26/2021,$1018.43,62414970,$1024.69,$1094.94,$1001.44
10/25/2021,$1024.86,62852100,$950.53,$1045.02,$944.2
10/22/2021,$909.68,22880840,$895.5,$910,$890.96'''

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text))

print( df['Date'] )

# remove `$` and convert `string` to `float`
for column_name in ['Close/Last', 'Open', 'High', 'Low']:
    df[column_name] = df[column_name].str.replace('$', '', regex=False).astype(float)

ax = df.plot(x='Date', y='Open')
df.plot(x='Date', y='High', ax=ax)  # plot in the same `ax`
df.plot(x='Date', y='Low', ax=ax)   # plot in the same `ax`   
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

You can also plot all at once

```
df.plot(x='Date', y=['Open', 'High', 'Low'])
```

or use `bars` instead `lines` for `volumne`

```
df.plot(kind='bar', x='Date', y='Volume')
```

Comment: I changed full code to plot `Open`, `High`, `Low` in one chart.

Answer (score 0):

you can read the file containing the data as a pandas dataframe and then select the column you want
In `Python 3.X`:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
arr = df['col_name']
```

and then you can use any of the pre-implemented functions in pandas or use `matplotlib` or any other visualization python package you prefer
you can install any package by using the following command in your terminal/command prompt
`pip install -U python_pkg`